# Unable to resume activity: provider doesnt exist

Tags: android, exception, networking

I use network provider to update location in my app. But i cant stand whats the problem.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //mMockLocationProvider = new MockLocationProvider(
    //      LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this);


    if (null == (mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)))
        finish();
    mLastLocationReading = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if((null == mLastLocationReading)||(age(mLastLocationReading)>FIVE_MINS)){
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mMinTime, mMinDistance,this); 
    }




}
```

Here is the log cat

```
03-14 05:20:17.727: E/AndroidRuntime(2256): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 05:20:17.727: E/AndroidRuntime(2256): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {course.labs.locationlab/course.labs.locationlab.PlaceViewActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider doesn't exisit: null
03-14 05:20:17.727: E/AndroidRuntime(2256):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();

//mMockLocationProvider = new MockLocationProvider(
//      LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, this);

mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

if (mLocationManager == null)
    finish();
mLastLocationReading = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

if((mLastLocationReading == null)||(age(mLastLocationReading)>FIVE_MINS)){
mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, mMinTime, mMinDistance,this); 
}

}
```